# How do I float images next to logo?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, styling

I'm using Wordpress 5.2.2 with Newspress Extend theme as the parent.

I restored the default settings of the theme in Appearance --> Newspress Options in an attempt to fix something unrelated, and lost the custom html/inline css that floated the advertisements, one left and one right to be sandwiching the logo. Oops. I tried to guess the replacement code based on my very limited knowledge of html/css and it's rendering them above not only the logo, but the top menu as well. I know this change can be done in this section because I'm just trying to restore it to what it was from the previous developer. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Appearance --> Newspress Options --> General Options --> Custom code within Head area (all pages)

```
<a href=https://www.flalottery.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/FLO_16975_Education-Print-Ad-Ebony-News-Today_10.625x10.445-GLOBE-C.jpg" alt="fla lottery" style="float:left; max-width: 25%;"></a>

<a href="https://www.southeasternhonda.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/SEH_EbonyNewsAd_OCT2017-1.jpg" alt="southeastern honda"/ style="float: right; max-width: 25%;"></a>
```

[custom css screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBsJZ.jpg)

[logo screenshot in Newspress theme's custom interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRAOy.jpg)

[page in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yfrY.jpg)

Comment: Not too familiar with your WordPress setup, but the code should go inside of a `<body>` section as opposed to a `<head>` section> There's likely an equivalent area to enter such code. You'll probably want to 'sandwich' your logo's code. Also, you're missing the opening `"` in your first link, which may cause the hyperlink to 'bleed' onto the rest of the content.

Comment: Okay, I added the " and put in in the <body> section, but it's the exact same when I saved and refreshed (weird). Before, whatever syntax that placed them either side of the logo was in the same section I used under the <head>, so I'm thinking there's a way to put it inline with the logo...

Answer (score 0):

Your ads are sitting outside of the container div.  They're actually sitting above the site's metatags at the moment.  CSS is a powerful tool, but it shouldn't be used to over-correct or mask improper HTML structure. You need to stuff your ads into their respective divs.

This is how your HTML should look, specifically for your header div:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="header-content">

    <!-- Site Titele and Description Goes Here -->
    <div class="topadlft"><a href="https://www.flalottery.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/FLO_16975_Education-Print-Ad-Ebony-News-Today_10.625x10.445-GLOBE-C.jpg" alt="fla lottery"></a><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/themes/newspress-extend/images/ad3.png"></a></div> 
    <a href="https://ebonynewstoday.com/"><img class="site-logo" src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Ebony_LOGOHorizontal_Color.gif"><h1 class="site-title-hidden">Ebony News Today</h1></a>

    <h2 class="site-title-hidden">"The Heartbeat of Our Community"</h2>        
    <div class="topadrt"><a href="https://www.southeasternhonda.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/SEH_EbonyNewsAd_OCT2017-1.jpg" alt="southeastern honda"></a><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://ebonynewstoday.com/wp-content/themes/newspress-extend/images/ad3.png"></a></div> 

    </div><!-- header-content -->
    <div class="heading-date">Friday, October 4, 2019</div>  
    </div>
```

You will also want to turn off the "display:none;" selectors in your CSS file for the "topadlft" and "topadrt" classes.  Also remove the inline styles from each ad image. You're going to want the div classes that contain the ads to do the heavy lifting here.  Inline styles will just cause further complications.

Once you've addressed the above, you should wind up with something that looks like this:

[Fixed Header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GF0j.png)